# How to find multiline text between curly braces?

Tags: python, regex

I have next input string:

```
ANIM "_NAME_KEY_" // Index = 26, AFrames = 1
    {
        0x301C
        AF  0x201C  1   0   0   FREE_ROTATE 0   FREE_SCALE_XY 100 100
    }
```

How can i get whole string between two curly braces, just having _NAME_KEY_ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Use the option `re.MULTILINE` as a second argument to your re.compile/etc. call.</strike>

I would propose this regex: `_NAME_KEY_[^{]*+\{([^}]+)\}`

**Explanation:**

`_NAME_KEY_`: match "_NAME_KEY_"

`[^{]*`: match as many non-{-characters as possible (greedy)

`\{`: match a { character

`([^}]+)`: match (and capture) non-}-characters (greedy)

`\}`: match one } character

Comment: i'm using 
`query = "ANIM \"" + _KEY_NAME_ + "\".*(\s*)" + "{(\s*\w){2}\s*}"
match = re.search(query, self.content, re.MULTILINE)` 
but it's working just with 2 lines inside curly braces.

Comment: No, the `MULTILINE` option merely changes the behavior of the anchors, `^` and `$`.  You aren't using the anchors, so `MULTILINE` is irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't `MULTILINE` relevant for what the dot matches?

**edit:** Right. I'm not using dots. Okay, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall(r'(?<={)[^}]*',str)
```

E.g.

```
In [5]: x="""ANIM "_NAME_KEY_" // Index = 26, AFrames = 1
    {
        0x301C
        AF  0x201C  1   0   0   FREE_ROTATE 0   FREE_SCALE_XY 100 100
    }"""

In [6]: import re

In [7]: re.findall(r'(?<={)[^}]*',x)
Out[7]: ['\n        0x301C\n        AF  0x201C  1   0   0   FREE_ROTATE 0   FREE_SCALE_XY 100 100\n    ']
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
_NAME_KEY_[^{]*\{([^}]*)}
```

The result is in the first capturing group. you don't need to use the dotall mode since this pattern doesn't use the dot.

As an aside notice, you can trim white spaces like that:

```
_NAME_KEY_[^{]*\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}
```